# Importing a JavaScript function in TypeScript and AngularJS 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a plugin that works with JavaScript. I want to use the function inside of my TypeScript component in AngularJS2. I have used different kinds of ways with no success.

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.0, node: 7.7.2, @angular/core: 2.4.9
```

Let's assume I want to use the following function cube.js:

```
function cube(x) {
   return x * x * x;
}
const foo = Math.PI + Math.SQRT2;
export default { cube, foo };
```

Using Type Definition approach, I create cube.d.ts as follows:

```
interface Cube {
   cube(x:number):number;
} 
export default Cube;
```

In my component, I have imported the function as follows:

```
import Cube from './cube';
...
public myCube:Cube;
console.log(myCube.cube(3));
```

But it gives me the following error:

> Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'cube' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'cube' of undefined
>       at HComponent.webpackJsonp

in tsconfig.json, allowJS is true (edited: "allowJs": true). @type module has already been installed. Still Can not read a simple JS function.

Any idea?

Comment: Try instancing it `constructor(private myCube: Cube) {}` in the constructor

Comment: Incuding in constructor did not work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer.

My cube.js file:

```
"use strict"; 
class Cube {
    cube(x) {
     return x * x * x;
   }
}
export default Cube;
```

My cube.d.ts file

```
export default class Cube {
  cube(x: number): number;
}
```

In the ts component, I have:

```
/// <reference path="./cube.d.ts" />
import Cube from './cube';
...
        const my = new Cube();
        console.log(my.cube(10));
```

Comment: Just a comment for anyone else coming here as a newbie to TS.  I had to also turn on the flag in tsconfig.json `"declaration": true` to make this solution work.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
import model = require('../../model');
```

And in my component

```
model.functionName();
```

Comment: Error--> Cannot find name 'require'.) . Even after writing: declare var require: any; I have the above-mentioned error.